# Creating complex table structure without using css

Tags: html

I am trying to make this table in HTML without using CSS, but I am not getting the desired output. I have tried a bunch of other combinations for the row with 6:2:3 rowspan.

This is the desired output [image]

This is the code I am using.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
        <th rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of table, I suggest searching and playing a bit with CSS Grid. Jen Simmons does some great talks, one of her examples matches closely to what you're trying to learn: https://labs.jensimmons.com/2017/01-011.html

Comment: Noticed your constraint "without CSS": why?

Comment: If it works consider green tick!

Answer (score 1):

Done Heights may not be set but it works properly

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table style="width:100%;margin-top:50px;">
              <tr>
                <td>6</td>

              </tr>

            </table>
          </td>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>


      </table>




    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>

      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="not">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>21</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```